# Singular value decomposition of a three-dimensional array

Tags: svd

The ***Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)*** of a matrix is
$$A_{m\times n} = U_{m\times m}\Lambda_{m\times n} V_{n\times n}'$$
where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $\Lambda$ has (*i*, *i*) entry $\lambda_i \geq 0$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots , min(m, n)$ and the other entries are zero. Then the *left singular vectors*  $U$  for rows of matrix and *right singular vectors* $V$  for columns of matrix can be plotted on the same graph called ***bi-plot***.

I'm wondering how to do the ***SVD*** of a three dimensional array and plot the singular vectors on the same graph like ***bi-plot***.

Thanks

Comment: please do not [cross-post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32702/singular-value-decomposition-svd-of-a-three-dimensional-array).

Comment: Could you explain what the analog of matrix multiplication might be for a "three-dimensional array" (presumably, a rank-three array requiring three independent indexes)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several notions of decomposition of such a tensor. Last year I asked [essentially the same question](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/97377-Decompose-A-Third-Order-Tensor-Into-Pure-Tensors) on the MaplePrimes site, answered it myself by referring to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition), and provided an implementation for one of those notions (the CANDECOMP/PARAFAC decomposition) in a [follow-up post](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/97861-CANDECOMPPARAFAC-Images-As-Tensors-Of-Order-3) (applied to decomposing the $3\times m \times n$ tensor given by the R,G,B entries of an image).

Comment: +1 Cool!  (BTW, the links to the MaplePrimes site are returning a 404.)

Comment: @whuber: there was a temporary outage - I believe the links should work again.

Comment: Thanks.  The site's a little slow but it's working now.  I like the image examples.

Comment: Nice. Any idea about plotting the singular vectors. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: I think you can do the same as with a regular SVD - create points $(d_1^\alpha u_{1i}, d_2^\alpha u_{2i})$, $(d_1^\alpha v_{1i}, d_2^\alpha v_{2i})$, $(d_1^\alpha w_{1i}, d_2^\alpha w_{2i}$ for $i = 1, \dotsc, n$, where $u_1, v_1, w_1$ are the 1st triple of "singular" vectors and $d_1$ the 1st singular value - similar for 2nd. (I had to look biplots up - hadn't seen them before.) By the way - I think you'd potentially get a more powerful (3D) graph if you include the third singular vector as a third coordinate...